# Conditions for this function to be a Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am having a hard time understanding the next problem. I fail to understand how the sum works here and how to address the problem.

> Let $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ disjoint subsets of $\Omega$, and real numbers respectively. Determine the conditions under which the following function is a random variable.
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{A_i}$,
>
> Where $1_{A_i}$ is the indicator function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A random variable with respect to what $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @LorenzoNajt, this is the complete statement of the problem. I was thinking to assume that the $A_i$'s belong a $\sigma-algebra$, and use that the real numbers belong to the Borel $\sigma-algebra$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: First suppose the $a_i$ are all distinct and let $X$ denote the function given in the problem.  Then what is $X^{-1}(a_i)$?  What is the difference if we allow , e.g. $a_i=a_j$ for two particular $i,j$?

Comment: " use that the real numbers belong to the Borel σ−algebra of R." This statement is incorrect : the $a_i$ are not themselves subsets of the real numbers. It seems to me that the problem is asking you to determine the minimal sigma algebra necessary for that function to be a measurable. Brians hint will help you figure this out.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt, okay. So $X^{-1}(\sum_{j \in J}a_{i_j})=\cap_{j \in J} A_{i_j}$? Assuming $a_k \neq a_r$.

Comment: Edit: $X^{-1}(\sum_{j \in J} a_{i_j})=\cup_{j \in J} A_{i_j}$.

Comment: $a_i$'s must be different prime numbers, none of them equal to 2.